# Product of diagonal and non-symmetric matrices diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

I have an (n x n) matrix D such that: D = A.B.C

where A and C are diagonal matrices with non-zero values on the diagonal, and B is a non-symmetric matrix.

My question is whether can we say something on D being diagonalizable? If yes, how could we prove this? Is there a general rule?

Comment: In general of course the answer is no: take $A=I,C=I$ and hence $D=B$.

Comment: That's a fair point, Artem. Thanks. I just wanted to make sure that I'm not missing anything with respect to a non-symmetric matrix being multiplied on both sides by diagonal matrices. I guess the only way where D would have n distinct eigenvalues is that B be a symmetric, positive matrix, or use the Perron-Frobenius theorem.